# C++ Object Database

Tags: c++, core-data, object-oriented-database

I am working on my bachelor's thesis. It's goal is to write Object Database(Similar to CoreData) in C++. One of the requirements is to support reflective relations ( 1-1,1-M,M-M) and dynamic object loading.

My current design consists of simple DDL language with code generation. 
User writes his classes he wants to persist, then writes relations between these classes. Something like this:

```
Person {
    string name;
    int salary;
}
relation Person.boss(1) references Person inverse Person.subs(M);
```

From this, I generate C++ header with class definition, C++ source with method definitions.  Class has all primitive fields as public, relations are private, and only accessible by get/set or get/add/remove/clear methods.
In these methods, I preserve consistency of reflexive relations.
For example: in method `setBoss` I would do following:

```
void setBoss(ptr<Person> val) {
        if (boss) {
            boss->subs.remove(this);
        }
        boss = val;
        boss->subs.add(this);
        boss.modified = true
    }
```

This code is all generated, and works. But my supervisor requires I do this without any form of code generation, and try to follow CoreData as close as possible. I think his idea is to simulate dynamic object in C++, where each object that can be stored in database contains `map<string,value>`, and fields read from this map. I think this design is clearly wrong for C++, since storing everything like this would require that each field is custom class that has reference to owner and  dynamic cast on each field access, and I'm not even talking about storing other classes, which use custom shared pointer(it's a template, therefore dynamic cast will not work).

Also ,there is a problem with metadata, how do I define schema in this system ? I probably could use a visitor, that visits all the fields, and using some macro trickery retrieves their name and type, but reflexive relations ? I don't know.

In my approach, I can somehow version added fields and generate migration code for them. (storing schema version inside persistent database, then, when I open this database, check version and run generated migration code).

Is there something I am missing here ? Is my approach totally wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

[of course, the below is an opinion, but blame the question, not me]

> Is there something I am missing here ? Is my approach totally wrong ?

Totally wrong - no. But not devoid of risks.

One of the disadvantages of your approach (an ORM-like one): each time you change you structures, "data store migration" is going to be a nightmare. Or you'll have to impose on the users (fellow programmers) the nightmare of dealing with different versions of a schema.

Have a look on Google's [`protobuff`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) for a taste of problems with generated structures undergoing evolution - they aren't dealing with storage, just with data-transmission. And yet you have to navigate carefully (what members are required/optional) and obey some strict rules (e.g. between to versions of your protocol, just add but **never remove** fields).

> Also ,there is a problem with metadata, how do I define schema in this system ?

Isn't this a wonderful topic for your thesis? Of course it isn't going to be trivial, but why it should be?

Comment: Well, with my approach, generating schema is pretty doable, since I am generating code, I can generate method that takes some `context` object, and calls `generateTable`, `addAttribute` methods on this context. Migrations are also possible(annotate added fields in DDL, then generate migration code with them). With my supervisor's approach , not so much.

Comment: "Migrations are also possible(annotate added fields in DDL, then generate migration code with them)" I beg to disagree. If your changes are only additions then *of course* everything is going to be fine. However, try to change a 1-M to M-M and see what this is going to do with the code calling your older version. " With my supervisor's approach , not so much." With your supervisor's approach there's no need to.

Comment: I don't understand,there will always be a need to update the schema after migration.

Comment: It's not about the schema update, it's about the code running on top of it. With a runtime `map<name,value>` approach, as stupid and non-structured as it looks at the first sight, the old code will continue to compile and work (that's not necessarily an advantage - as it may work badly) - just look of how many generic JSON libs are outthere. In your approach, any change of the schema will mandate at least recompilation (if this recompilation is even possible without modification of the old code using newer structures)

Comment: Well, there are 2 primary actions, reading an object, writing an object to database. Both use visitor that visits all class fields and does the necessary thing. If code is running on newer database with additional attributes, those attributes are ignored, removed attributes can be set to null/default value.

Comment: "Well, there are 2 primary actions, reading an object, writing an object to database" True for *your* code. But my code, the one that consumes the generated structures, is going to be busted without a recompilation against the new generated structures, be it only because `sizeof(OldA) != sizeof(NewA)`.

Comment: Look, I'm not saying that your solution is flawed and neither that your solution is perfect. Neither saying the same for what your supervisor has in mind. I do say that neither of the solution *is absolutely best all the time*: under some circumstances your approach will have an upper hand, in others the generic one will be better. And I certainly do hope you don't cast me (us?) in the shoes of your supervisor only to have someone to argue safely.

Comment: No, I am only trying to figure out how can I implement what he wants from me. Also, YOU generate the structures. You as an application developer need to persist some objects, therefore you write your classes and relations in DDL, and use cli tool to generate safe C++ source that can load/store/query for objects using my library, library will work on any class that has certain suite of methods ( methods needed for schema creation, maybe migration,field visitation for purpose of loading/storing objects ). At least that was my original idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125477/discussion-between-semtexzv-and-adrian-colomitchi).

Answer (score 0):

Without code generation, you have to choose between a compiled-level approach -- using a DSL -- or a runtime-centric approach -- using some blend of virtual functions, dynamic casting, and typeid/typeindex.

The DSL exercise is something we happened to have gone through this year, and, ironically, it relates very closely to your question: 1-1, 1-N, N-N collections specifically. Surely, this would be an overkill for the Bachelor's thesis, but here's how it may look like: https://github.com/C5T/Current/blob/1b9716438d323b8b47eb8d5bf5907e98ee3be1dc/Storage/test.cc#L92-L120

In your case, I'd start by asking the supervisor directly whether they are looking for compile-time or runtime solution. Runtime is probably easier to implement time- and LOC-wise, but it would offer considerably less guarantees, and the result would be less practical. For string <=> string mappings only though, a couple collections and virtually-referenced policy classes may well do the job.

Comment: I tried DSL, but generating reflexive relations would require a *LOT* of macros, instead, I opted in to own language with tool to generate needed code. And yes, after last meeting with him , I got the idea he wants me to do everything dynamic, something like `DbVal` class from which `DbInt,DbFloat,DbString` inherit, and store `map<string,DbVal>` inside object as data storage, but he also wants attributes to be retrievable by field acces, that means the class fields would have to have reference to owner class, and read from this field would be read from said map.

Comment: It's a great exercise. I'd be grateful to have such a teacher.